# Download open java sdk in a docker file

Tags: java, linux, docker, dockerfile

I am absolute noob to linux and docker and I am just trying to learn things as I do it. I am creating a docker file to run xamarin build machine, and I have difficulties in installing the Open Java sdk. The mono runtime seems to install correctly.

```
FROM debian:stretch-slim

RUN apt-get update && \
apt-get install curl unzip java-1.8.0-openjdk-headless java-1.8.0- 
openjdk-devel -y  && \
apt-get clean all
```

Error

```
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
E: Unable to locate package java-1.8.0-openjdk-headless
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'java-1.8.0-openjdk-headless'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'java-1.8.0-openjdk-headless'
E: Unable to locate package java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel'
The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get update &&     apt-get install curl 
unzip java-1.8.0-openjdk-headless java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel -y  &&     
apt-get clean all' returned a non-zero code: 100
```

Note: I have removed the Mono installation code to make it easy to read.

I appreciate if you can tell me what causes the issue, and how can I fix it.

Comment: Not able to findout package java-1.8.0-openjdk-headless. You have to wget java package and install

Comment: @GovindParashar : Is that absolutely needed, I don't see wget in any of the examples of docker file. Can u please show how that code will look like

Comment: is `openjdk-8-jre-headless` and or `openjdk-8-jdk`  is the package that you are looking for?

Comment: @MaozZadok: Yes looking for openjdk-8-jre-headless as its more lightweight and I don't really need any gui stuffs

Comment: @LibinJoseph : You will find useful  code here https://github.com/docker-library/openjdk

Comment: You can always use curl/wget: https://github.com/mkowsiak/ProfilerDocker/blob/master/Dockerfile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there are some issues with debian:stretch-slim and openjdk-8 including openjdk-8-jre-headless, try use the latest debian `FROM debian:latest` or tag 7-slim

Comment: and run `apt-get install openjdk-8-jre-headless`

Comment: I tried changing the base image to debian:latest, but same error

Comment: Sorry, I missed your comment, Its working now. Thank you for the help